# Connect Oracle Database from Google App Engine with Node JS

Tags: node.js, oracle, google-app-engine, instantclient

We have configured Google VPC to connect Internal Network from Google Cloud. We are having Oracle Database and we are trying to connect this database from App Engine via Node JS (Standard Environment preferred). I have written a Node JS application that can connect Oracle Database locally (may be with some other clients installed on my system). Here is my Application structure -

[image]

Here is my app.yaml file -

```
runtime: nodejs10
env_variables:
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH: "/instantclient"
```

Here is my app.js file -

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var path = require('path');
//process.env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = path.join(__dirname, '/instantclient'); //+ ';' + process.env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'];
//console.log(process.env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']);

process.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH = 'instantclient';
console.log(process.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  oracledb.getConnection(
    {
      user: 'user_id',
      password: 'password',
      connectString:
        '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dbhost)(PORT=1521)(SEND_BUF_SIZE=)(RECV_BUF_SIZE=))(LOAD_BALANCE=yes))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=dbhost)))',
    },
    connExecute
  );

  function connExecute(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.send(err.message);
      return;
    }
    sql = 'Select * from table_name';
    connection.execute(
      sql,
      {},
      {outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT}, 
      function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);

          res.send(err.message);
          connRelease(connection);
          return;
        }
        var ping = require('ping');

        var hosts = ['dbhost'];

        hosts.forEach(function(host) {
          ping.promise.probe(host).then(function(res) {
            var png = JSON.stringify(res);
            console.log(res);

          });
        });
        console.log(result.metaData);
        console.log(result.rows);
        jsonstring = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
        res.send(jsonstring);
        connRelease(connection);
      }
    );
  }

  function connRelease(connection) {
    connection.close(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
    });
  }
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I have deployed the APP in App Engine. After hitting URL, its throwing me below error -

```
DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig. If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
```

I have verified that "libclntsh.so" file already there in "instantclient" folder. Am I doing something wrong here or this is at all not possible?

**EDIT**
As suggested by @Dan McGhan, I have added `/srv/instantclient` in my app.yaml and got below error -

```
Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/srv/instantclient/libclntsh.so: file too short"
```

I simply remove the file `libclntsh.so` and copied + renamed file `libclntsh.so.19.1` as `libclntsh.so`. Now getting below error -

```
libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to add this or solve this issue?

**NOTE:** Mentioned file not present in instantclient folder.

***UPDATE & RESOLUTION:***

Thankfully problem resolved by manually adding `"libaio.so.1"` file from a Linux system to `"instantclient"` folder.

Comment: Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH via the app.yaml is probably required (you can remove the lines of code in the app attempting to do the same). In your app, the Instant Client files are in `instantclient`. However, when your app is deployed, what is the full path to that directory? That's what you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to.

Comment: @DanMcGhan I removed those lines as suggested. Also added `/srv/instantclient` in app.yaml. Now error message changed to - `Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/srv/instantclient/libclntsh.so: file too short".`

Comment: How did you determine that `/srv` was the correct path? What did you download for the Instant Client (exactly which file, version, OS)? Please show us the contents of the instantclient directory contents.

Comment: @DanMcGhan  Log - `A 2019-11-18T15:44:36.154944Z App listening on port 8081 
  undefined
A 2019-11-18T15:44:36.119757Z /srv/instantclient `  structure of folder -  `adrci
BASIC_LICENSE
BASIC_README
genezi
libclntsh - Copy.so
libclntsh.so
libclntsh.so.10.1
libclntsh.so.11.1
libclntsh.so.12.1
libclntsh.so.18.1
libclntsh.so.19.1
libclntshcore.so.19.1
libipc1.so
libmql1.so
libnnz19.so
libocci.so
libocci.so.10.1
libocci.so.11.1
libocci.so.12.1
libocci.so.18.1
libocci.so.19.1
libociei.so
libocijdbc19.so
liboramysql19.so
network
ojdbc8.jar
ucp.jar
uidrvci
xstreams.jar`

Comment: Why would the log file point to `/srv/instantclient`?

Comment: Also, please answer the other question: What did you download for the Instant Client (exactly which file, version, OS)? Here's another one: What OS is App Engine using?

Comment: @DanMcGhan Not very sure. Most probably due to these lines - `process.env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = path.join(__dirname, '/instantclient'); //+ ';' + process.env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'];
console.log(process.env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']);`

Comment: Okay, fair enough. What did you download for the Instant Client (exactly which file, version, OS)? Here's another one: What OS is App Engine using?

Comment: @DanMcGhan Downloaded for 64 bit Linux .. BASIC PACKAGE (ZIP) - https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html

Comment: @DanMcGhan How do I know what OS App Engine is using ??? Its Standard Env

Comment: @DanMcGhan Can you please let me know how to add Oracle Instant Client on Standard App Engine ?

Comment: I don't know anything about App Engine, but the binaries you downloaded were specific to Linux x64. It seems that the standard environment tries to abstract away the OS layer, so I'm not sure you'll be able to use it. Does it have `libaio` installed? You may need to play with more logging from the app to check some of these things out.

Comment: As per my knowledge Standard App Engine is like a Sandbox solution. Probably you can't configure the O/S directly. Don't know whether '`libaio` is installed or not. May be not.

Comment: @DanMcGhan Got this from App Engine - `A 2019-11-18T17:07:41.245629Z linux 
A 2019-11-18T17:07:41.245220Z 4.4.0 
A 2019-11-18T17:07:41.245070Z Linux 
A 2019-11-18T17:07:41.244949Z /srv/instantclient` ... And from my local system - `Windows_NT
10.0.17134
win32
App listening on port 8080
Press Ctrl+C to quit.`

Comment: I think you'll need to switch to the flexible version.

Comment: Alternatively, you could front-end your database with something like ORDS and then interact with the database over HTTPS from the standard environment. https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/rest.html

Comment: @DanMcGhan Thankfully problem resolved by manually adding `"libaio.so.1"` file from a Linux system to `"instantclient"` folder.

Comment: Can you provide full details of this issue fix .I am also facing same issue